# How to retain the data while clicking on the cancel button in page.?

Tags: java, struts

I have a Employee add page which has lot of information to be filled. So, user requested 'copy info' functionality from other Employee..On top of the add page i have 'copy info' button which in turn redirects to another page which lists all employees. from that user select one of the employee and whose informations are copied to this add page. untill this it is fine.

If the user filled some information in add page and clicks on 'copy info' button and in the second page if he clicks on cancel, it should comes back to add bage with information what he was filled. I am not able to hold the filled information. Any idea to have the filled information other than storing it in session?
If code is reqired to undestand better will be posted.let me know.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object, which fields are the form fields, and pass it down to your page. This object will not be destroyed as the parent class still holds the pointer.

Comment: From the second page what type of redirection should i use. because if i use redirect all the values get initialized. i am not able to keep that object in hand.